# Json response not coming for some foods from fitbit api

Tags: java, json, spring-restcontroller, fitbit

I am trying get the food logs data from fitbit by date. The url which I hit is **https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/foods/log/date/[date].json**. I have written the below code to get the json response.

```
public class FoodNutritionalLog {
private int calories;
private double carbs;
private double fat;
private double fiber;
private double protein;
private double sodium;
```

}

I am able to get this part from response for few foods but not for all foods. But,I checked in **https://apigee.com/me3/embed/console/fitbit** here I am able to get nutritional info for all the foods that I have logged.

Fitbit api url **https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/food-logging/**